# Associate Simple Products with Custom Options to Configurable Product

Tags: custom-options, configurable-product

I am working on an inventory of 700+ simple products with custom options. I would like to make a a configurable product and associate these simple products WITH existing custom options.
Is this doable? Whats the best method to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Programmatically you mean?

Comment: Yea, by whatever mean possible.

Comment: @sunny155 did you got any solution please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to reconsider what you want to do as it creates conflicts on almost every aspect of Magento. Consider this:

1. Custom Options are meant for end user to "fine-tune" product. Predefining them in configurable product removes their main purpose. This argument alone hints that there must be an another way to do whatever you want to do.
2. Configured products have their own list of options. I don't think there's a simple way to build nested lists without rewriting pretty much everything from wish-list to credit memos. As an additional "bonus" update so extensive renders whole installation pretty much unupgradable.
3. Even if you manage to find workaround from this problem programmatically, there's no way to set custom options for simple products on the backend, making any product created this way a bag of hurt.
4. You can add Custom Options to configurable product themselves. This almost certainly creates its own set of issues.

It's much easier to generate a new simple product with appropriate attribute value and use that instead. And even if you need to integrate it with external inventory system, it's way easier to modify than rewriting better part of Magento.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite

> Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection

And disable the checkdata call for your product type under AssignProducts().

For example:

```
if($parentQuote->getData('product_type')!="configurable"){
              $item->checkData();
}
```

This will prevent Magento from checking for required options on products associated with the parent product type. (I have only tested this on Bundles so let me know if this doesn't work in your case).

If you want the customer to choose these options you could just recreate em by getting the associated products on the config product page and display the custom options like on a regular page. After this you could rewrite the add to cart indexcontroller and add the options to the children items.